# How to list all files with only arbitrary file path read, but no directory listing nor sudo?

Tags: linux, directory-traversal

I have found a [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) vulnerability that allows me to read any path on the server that does not require `sudo`.

To fully exploit this, I would like to know which files exist in each directory so I can read them.

In other words, I can do `cat /any/path`, but not `ls /any/path` nor `sudo cat /any/path`. So how can I find as many files as possible to `cat` them (without trying all possibilities...)

Reading special files like dev or proc, or files present on most Linux distributions is OK. For example, if I could read `locate`s `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` database the problem would be solved: but I can't because I don't have `sudo`.

If there is no ideal answer that lists *all* files, I am also interested in answers that list large number of existing files.

In this particular instance, the traversal happens inside a remote VM, so privilege escalation in itself is not the main goal: what I'm interested in is confidential source code that may be found on the VM. But very common privilege escalation paths are also welcome as those would give us `mlocate` and solve the problem, besides being directly useful in other systems.

More precisely, the system in my case is a build on push Git service analogous to GitHub / GH pages (assuming each Jekyll build runs on VM, which I don't know). Mentioning this because it has already been fixed by vendors of course :) It is me who creates the Git repo: that is the attack vector, so reading the Git repository is not very interesting.

Comment: One process you can access is the one currently running the command: `/proc/self`. Here `self` is a symlink alias of the it's PID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try other locate implementations that index world-accessible files in a world-readable index, typically located at `/var/lib/locate/locatedb` or `/var/cache/locate/locatedb` or some such.

I don't see a lot of need for file listing to escalate your access on a typical server. Usually you'd know what application you're attacking and retrieve its configuration files and its database and obtain credentials this way. You might try files such as `.netrc`, `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/config` to see if the account can be a gateway into other accounts. If you aren't sure what may be running on the box, try lots and lots of plausible file names.

The one thing that's a bit long to exhaust is the PID values, to explore what's running. It takes 32k requests to exhaust `pid_t` under Linux by default, and you can check the maximum value in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. The command line is in `/proc/PID/cmdline`; you don't get to see the list of open files (you need `readlink` for that) but you can see their content (`cat /proc/PID/fd/0` …).

For the specific case of a build service, do check the configuration files of that service. That should help you locate the git repository. If you've been able to locate a git checkout, look in `.git/index` and `.git/logs/HEADS` and perhaps other files in `.git/logs` (experiment with that service to see which branches are used and what operations it uses). This should let you retrieve object IDs which you can then read from `.git/objects`.

Other than finding a locate database, I can't think of a way to elevate read-files access into list-files with a typical configuration.

Answer (score 1):

On some versions of Unix (especially older ones),
you may be able to `cat` directories themselves; e.g., `cat /any` or even `cat /`. 
The result will be a binary file whose format is different on different versions of Unix,
but which will always contain the names of all the entries in the directory
(starting with `.` and `..`) and their inode numbers (in binary form). 
So, for example, the output of `cat /` will include `any`, etc.

See [When did directories stop being readable as files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154119/23408)